# How To Use NDB Query Without Knowing Class Name

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm writing a Python app on Google App Engine and I need to have an ndb query but the problem is that the query can be on different class types so I'm looking for a method other than `clss.Query()`. I need `clss` to be a variable. Also could I possibly use a filter with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is in fact a way to do this that is mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query):

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
ndb.Query(kind=clss)
```

You could also use filters, either by passing the filter as a parameter in the query:

```
ndb.Query(kind=clss, filters=...)
```

or by applying a `filter()` on the query like you would usually do:

```
ndb.Query(kind=clss).filter()
```

Comment: Excellent, except that, if `clss` is a *variable* as the OP posits, you absolutely must lose the quotes you're using -- `kind=clss` is right, **not** `kind="clss"` where the quotes would make the RHS into a *constant* literal string! Please fix this big oops (in three places) in your otherwise excellent answer...

Comment: @Alex Martelli thanks for the remark but I assumed that the person asking would understand that. I’m gonna try to make it clear.